InDesign: Align text in page spreads equally at bottom
I am not a DTP expert and I am only doing a one-off job for my own book. Please excuse my now knowing the correct terminology or what may be common knowledge for seasoned designers.
I am looking for an automatic solution for the following problem: in page spreads, the bottom-most lines do not always align symmetrically to the baseline grid. To fix this, I have been checking every spread and manually adjusting the leading and/or tracking until the bottom lines align with each other visually. Is there a way to do this automatically?
Please see attached screenshot showing how the left page has some vertical spacing from bottom, whereas the right page doesn't.

EDIT: I've tried Paragraph > Align to Baseline Grid either for the entire book or just for the current spread... This changes the leading drastically and makes it look pretty bad.
EDIT 2: I have adjusted and activated the text grid (Edit > Preferences > Grids > Baseline Grid) to be relative to the top margin (was top of page) and set it to increment every 15 pt as this is my leading for the body text. Citations have a leading of 14 pt.
I then edited all paragraph styles (all the headings, the body texts, the citations: Indents and Spacing > Align to Ggrid > All lines. And it seems to work in most cases – the page spears appear to align with each other at the bottom.
(I still have to redo all illustrations that were inserted using manual paragraph breaks.)


@cybernetic.nomad, thanks! Can you show me the step for these two options as I'm not sure where to find them?

I understand what's going wrong here, but it's not something I can easily explain in few words. Perhaps it's too much for one question. You need to understand leading, baseline grids, the "First Baseline Offset" setting in "Text Frame Options" and margins. You say this is a "one-off". Are you willing to dive into learning this?

More specifically I can tell you that the problem with the footnotes not aligning with the body text happens because the footnotes will align to the bottom of your text frame, but I can see that your body text doesn't align. There's a gap in the bottom which you need to eliminate by adjusting the height of all text frames. The total height of the text frame must be a multiple of the leading, BUT the first line can be set to have a different height than the others. I'll think about a way to explain this without spending hours.

@cybernetic.nomad, personally I think to justify the text vertically is a rather cheap solution. In a book the leading should be constant and the text should align to the same baseline grid.

Thanks for your input. I'll see what I can do and will post again. All day yesterday and for the most part of today, I was and will be fixing the manual overrides I had introduced to the text to make it align visually. I have one version of the book that looks 99.9% as it should, ready for printing, and I am working on a copy. I figured out the manual adjustments were "the way to madness" when I tried to export the book into EPUB. It was a disaster. That's why I started this reworking.

I have now created different styles for everything I need: headings, indented paragraphs, non-indented paragraphs, citations, footnotes, captions. And I have started applying the styles to text, one paragraph at a time. This is because, if I apply them bulk by left-clicking the style on a selection, the earlier formatting (different font face and leading) introduced by another person is applied. So, I need to right-click and choose "Clear character styles".

The good news is that, when I created the styles, I chose Align to grid: All lines under Indents and Spacing – and this seems to be producing the desired effect of automatic alignment to the bottom. Almost everywhere. I will finish removing all manual overrides, then fix all images and their captions, because they too were placed the wrong way I guess – by manually inserting new line breaks (not by me). Hopefully, there will be little need for manual adjustment. I will also try the settings suggested above.

To answer @Wolff's question if I am willing to dive into learning this: yes, I am, but I don't have a lot of time. My jobs are quite different and I am devoting time for this because the person in my university publishing house did a poor job (all manual adjustments to make things appear OK but they have never made an EPUB, which is when disaster strikes), so I decided to do it on my own. I have used InDesign before, about 15 years ago, when I was doing DTP for a local newspaper. But a newspaper is quite different from a book, I realise.

It looks like you are on the right track now! To make footnotes align with the text you still need to fix the gap between the bottom baseline and the bottom margin. Measure from the bottom of the page to the bottom baseline and set the bottom margin to that on all pages. If your text frames snap to the margins you can automatically adjust them all in one go by ticking on Adjust Layout. Beware that tiny rounding errors can cause the text frame to be a tiny bit too small to be able to contain the last line. If that happens, keep subtracting 0.001 mm from the bottom margin until the text fits.

@Wolff, thanks. I did it first by going to Type > Document Footnote Options > Layout > First Baseline > Offset : Ascent, Min: 4 mm. Then in the Footnote style I created, Indents and Spacing > Align to Grid: First Line Only, Space before/after set to 0. This is the only setting that got almost all footnotes (124 total) to align correctly. Changing Align to Grid to All Lines for example caused significant misalignment. I believe the final result is now a "job well done, although excellent". All of this with very few manual adjustments. I'm scared to try any other changes.
